# Change string between /

Tags: php, redirect

I'm getting my previous link like this:

```
$routeName = $request->headers->get("referer");
```

The result is :

```
http://pst.local:8888/nl/dashboard
```

How can I change the `nl` to `en`? So I can redirect.

Comment: More information please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply use [str_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

```
$routeName = $request->headers->get("referer");
$routeName = str_replace ($routeName, '/nl/', '/en/' );
```

If you are using symfony2 (*since you initially tagged this question as symfony2*) you might look into [locale](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/locale.html) and how to use that in routing.
Maybe you want to look into [routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html) in general since this normaly solves such problems almost *out of the box*?

Comment: Is this really the answer to his question? -> this is like random replacing.

Comment: It is what the OP requested isn't it?

Comment: I dont know. I thought he wants some kind of symfony2 methods or something, because he added symfony2 as Tag. This has nothing to do with symfony2

Comment: You were right with str_replace obviously, OP removed symfony2 as tag.

Comment: But the OP (*or some future visitor*) might look into routing now and learn about that. Can't be wrong to leave that information in there right?

Answer (score 0):

you may use this :

```
<?php
$html='http://pst.local:8888/nl/dashboard';
echo preg_replace('/(.*)\/.*?\/(.*)/', '\1/en/\2', $html);
```

this will speciafically replace the word before the last part of `/`

or you can use this if you want it to take the word before dashboard:

```
 echo preg_replace('/(.*)\/.*?\/(dashboard)/', '\1/en/\2', $html);
```